# Do Embeded Document in MongoDB always have to have _id field

Tags: mongodb

i am learning about MongoDB. I know that every document has an **_id** field unique in its collection. I have the question that do Embeded Document as value of fields in another document have to have **_id** field ?

Comment: If I understand your question... The field name `"_id"` will be present in every document at the root level.  You are free to use it, or not, in _subdocuments_ (aka, embedded documents).

Comment: The answer is no, embedded documents do need require this, if you're using a wrapper like `mongoose` often they will automatically generate such `_id`.

Comment: @tom-slabbaert your answer make me have wider view, thank you!